# DirectX 11: What happens if a depth stencil view is not bound to a render to texture

Tags: directx-11

As the question states:

I have an application (DX 11) where I have 2 views of a scene being rendered to a texture. And then in the main scene, I draw the main view and on top 2 smaller quads textured with the 2 views I rendered in the previous step.

I am not seeing any issue with the 2 rtts rendered. Shouldn't I be? I mean should not the depth test etc not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not bind a depth buffer to render into a render target, you can't use a depth or stencil test. It is the only "limitation".

If what you render in these two textures does not need a depth buffer to be correct, like 2D stuff, then you are free to go without one.